# SharePoint authentication

Tags: windows-authentication

SharePoint online is suddenly prompting for username and password and not accepting when saving to site from Office apps, it didn’t use to prompt at all.

I can access through office 365 sign in no problem and can access the whole site through explorer too.

FYI this is happening for all SharePoint site users

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated if not all good

Comment: fyi this is happening for all Sharepoint site users